# I am not getting pop up of google sign in, as if when I press the google sign in assigned button, it just shows blinks for a fraction of second

Tags: flutter, firebase

Google sign in popup is not showing, it just blinks for a partial second and I had created a function to change the screen after sign in, it is not happening too.

```
 _handleGoogleButton() {
    _signInWithGoogle().then((user) => Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
        )));
  }


  child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                  style: const ButtonStyle(
                      elevation: MaterialStatePropertyAll(8),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                          Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 200, 92))),
                  onPressed: _handleGoogleButton,
```

Comment: where's the definition of _signInWithGoogle? My guess is either it doesn't work bc of config issue (so add print and check error message if no handler) or you have signed in previously then it loads from cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are signed out, as this will be displayed initially. After that, it will only appear if you're not already signed in, and will prompt you to "Sign Out." I encountered the same problem, and logging out right before trying to open the Google account selection popup again was the solution for me. As a result, my code now looks like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  await _googleSignIn.signOut();
  await _googleSignIn.signIn();
}
```